# Sendemail Script do not works in Linux

Tags: linux, security, email

I'm creating a script to receive an email every time someone connects/logs in via SSH to my Linux server. The script is already working, but my issue is with sending the email.

I'm using the following command:

```
sendemail -f SENDER@outlook.com -t RECIPIENT@outlook.com -u "SSH LOGIN TO THE SERVER!" -m "ATTEMPTED LOGIN TO THE SERVER" -s smtp-mail.outlook.com:587 -xu SENDER@outlook.com -xp PASSWORD`
```

And I receive the following error:

> Jan 17 17:14:10 user sendemail[1700]: ERROR => TLS setup failed: hostname verification failed

[image: Error message]

I've tried it with port 25 and it returns timeout error:

> Jan 17 17:24:59 user sendemail[1711]: ERROR => Timeout while connecting to smtp-mail.outlook.com:25 There was no response after 60 seconds.

I tried with mutt and mailx as well, but it didn't work either...

I'm using an EC2 VM on AWS, and I've opened the ports in the firewall. Anyone know what might be the issue? I tested the same command locally on Ubuntu with the same credentials, and it works, but not on EC2.

Comment: do you mean `sendmail` or `send`e`mail`??

Comment: @MarcusMüller I meant 'sendemail,' but there's no such flag, so I used 'sendmail' instead.

Comment: don't do that! That tag refers to a different program, so incorrectly tagging it makes your question *worse*. I don't know `sendemail`, so I can't help with your problem :(

Comment: I'm sorry,  I didn't know..

Comment: Don't worry, no harm done :)

Comment: Your error image indicates an issue within the `SSL.pm` Perl library, so i assume you are using the Perl script [`sendemail.pl`](http://caspian.dotconf.net/menu/Software/SendEmail/).  Since that script's last release was in 2009, I am not sure how compatible it is with recent TLS.  If you know that it works on some servers but does not work for `outlook.com`, that could be a starting point for troubleshooting.  If you are using different software, you will need to clarify what it is so we have a reference to what you are doing.

Comment: What does the image show? Please [don't post pictures of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/100397)